# How to call componantDidMount in a component every time the prop I pass to it's value changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component called `Settings` that has four menu items. When one menu item gets clicked, the state of the selected menu item gets changed, then the component gets re rendered where a function called `this.returnForm()` gets called to pass the selected menu item state as a prop to another component called `GeneralSettings`.

```
class Settings extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        form_fields: ['Select option'],
        selectedSetting: 'general',
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

}

returnForm = (state) => {
    return <GeneralSettings selectedSetting={state}/>;
};

handleClick(event) {

    this.setState(
    {
        selectedSetting : event.currentTarget.dataset.settingspage
    }
    )

}

render() {
    return (
       <div className = "main-content-wrapper">

<div className="main-content-area settings" aria-hidden="false">

    <div className="destinations-filter">
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-content">
                <ul className="settings-list">
                    <li data-settingspage="general" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        <a><i
                            className="icon icon-settings-general"></i>General </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-settingspage="network" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        <a><i className="icon icon-settings-network"></i> Network</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-settingspage="security" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        <a><i className="icon icon-settings-security"></i> Security</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-settingspage="log" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        <a><i className="icon icon-settings-logs"></i> Logs</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div className="destinations-container">
    <div className="card">

        {this.returnForm(this.state.selectedSetting)}

    </div>
</div>

</div>



 </div>
   )
}
}
```

In the component called `GeneralSettings`, I have a `componentDidMount` method where I pass the selected menu item prop to a function called `getData()` to carry out the selected menu item specific logic.

```
class GeneralSettings extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.settingsUrls = [
        "/ui/settings/logging"
    ];

    this.state = {
        configSettings: {},
        formSchema: formSchema
    };

    this.configSettings = {};
    this.slected = "";

}
getData = (url, selectedSetting) => {
debugger;
fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                    response.status);
                return;
            }
            response.json().then((response) => {
                console.log(selectedSetting)
                let newFormSchema = this.setNonDefaultValues(response.data, formSchema.subsections);
                Object.assign(this.configSettings, response.data);
                this.setState({
                   configSettings : this.configSettings,
                    formSchema: newFormSchema
               });
            });
        }
    )
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    });
};

 componentDidMount() {
this.settingsUrls.map((settingUrl) => {
    this.getData(settingUrl,this.props.selectedSetting)
})

}

render() {

return (
    <div className="card-wrapper">
        <h2>{formSchema.label.toUpperCase()}</h2>
        {
            formSchema.subsections.map((subSection) => {
                return (
                    <>
                        <h3>{subSection['description']}</h3>
                        <div style={{marginBottom: '10px'}}></div>

                        {
                            subSection['input_fields'].map((inputField) => {
                                return buildForm(inputField, this.handleChange)
                            })
                        }
                        <hr></hr>
                    </>
                )
            })
        }
        <button className="button button-primary">Save Changes</button>
    </div>
 )
}

}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I select a new menu item in the `Settings` component and I pass the new selected menu item as a prop to the `GeneralSettings` component, the `ComponentDidMount` method doesn't get called again so I can't pass the new selected menu item to the `getData()` method. the component itself re renders however when a new menu item is clicked. If I was to `console.log(this.props.selectedSetting)` in the `render()` method of the `GeneralSettings` component and click the different menu items, it logs the different selected menu items. If I `console.log(this.props.selectedSetting)`in the `ComponentDidMount` method  of the `GeneralSettings` component, it only gets logged once in the initial render and when I click the different menu items after, nothing happens. Only when I refresh the page do I see something logged in `componentDidMount`

My understanding was that when a component gets re rendered, `componentDidMount` always gets called but what is happening here is `componentDidMount` gets called on the initial render when I load the page and then any render after that, `componentDidMount` doesn't get called and therefore I can't send the new selected menu item to my `getData` function.

So my question is this. How do I go about sending the new selected menu item to my `getData` function every time a new menu item gets clicked?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect, `componentDidMount` is only called *once*, when the component initially mounts. If you want to hook into the life cycle method that gets triggered when the props change, the correct one is `componentDidUpdate`. This is called when either the state or the props change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component is not remounted because you're changing just the prop, not the component.

So, with class components, the way to call a function on each prop change is with `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method ([doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)). Like so :

```js
componentDidUpdate() {
  this.settingsUrls.map(settingUrl => {
    this.getData(settingUrl,this.props.selectedSetting)
  })
}
```

Also, note that this method is not called for initial render, so you may want to have your `getData` in both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.